# Basic join query with SQLAlchemy, without tuples

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a really basic SQL query with SQLAlchemy involving a join of two tables `A` and `B`, with one FK from `B` to `A` and get the result of the join of the two tables as a plain list of objects, **without Python tuples**.

As an example, consider the tables `A` and `B` defined as:

```py
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "A"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)    
    field_a1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    field_a2 = db.Column(db.Integer)

class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "B"
    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('A.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
    field_b1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    field_b2 = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

The data stored in `A` and `B` is **in one-to-one correspondence**, and assume for instance they contain:

```
> SELECT * FROM A;
| id | field_a1 | field_a2 |
----------------------------
|  1 |        1 |        1 |
|  2 |        2 |        2 |
|  3 |        3 |        3 |

> SELECT * FROM B;
| a_id | field_b1 | field_b2 |
------------------------------
|    1 |       11 |       11 |
|    2 |       22 |       22 |
|    3 |       22 |       33 |
```

I would like to make a single query to get:

```
| id | field_a1 | field_a2 | field_b1 | field_b2 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1 |        1 |        1 |       11 |       11 |
|  2 |        2 |        2 |       22 |       22 |
|  3 |        3 |        3 |       22 |       33 |
```

I have tried to use `db.session.query(A, B).join(B, B.a_id == A.id)` but it gives outputs as a list of tuples of two objects `(A, B)`. I instead want a single object with all the fields of both `A` and `B` (with or without `a_id` which is redundant).

**Important:** I cannot modify class `A` (but I can modify `B`).

I have attempted to add `a = db.relationship('A', foreign_keys=[a_id])` in class `B`, and run the query as `B.query.options(db.lazyload('a'))`, yet the fields from `A` are only available as, e.g., `B.a.field_a1`.

I feel I'm missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to `query(*A.__table__.columns, *B.__table__.columns)`?

Comment: This worked! I combined that with one solution below to do: `db.session.query(*A.__table__.columns, *B.__table__.columns).join(B, B.a_id == A.id)`. The trick with `*` to avoid listing all the fields individually is what I have been missing. Thanks.

Comment: This trick with `*` is called [iterable unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/)

Comment: Even `.query(A.__table__, B.__table__).join(...)` would work I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.session.query(A).join(B, B.a_id == A.id)
```

Comment: From the limited tests that I could do, this seems to produce empty fields in the results for the fields of `B`. I could not track why.